# Is it important to rename image during upload

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I found some online tutorial on how to upload image in laravel but I noticed they rename with timestamp the image before the save the file name in the database, my question for this why we should rename the image name with timestamp ? is this for security reason ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its more of a practice.

Whatever the file name is we usually keep a record of it in our database and access it by it's `id`.

But we can keep things steady if we rename them and bring them all to the same convention.

More info on [laravel filesystems](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you would add a timestamp to an image is so you never end up accidentally overwriting another image of the same name.  You'll notice Laravel also does this when you create new migrations.  Depending on the logic of your application, you may want the ability to overwrite an image by uploading one with the same name, but normally this is not desired.  There are numerous ways to accomplish this however, adding a timestamp is just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is just the matter of interest. Renaming a file does not enhance security. The security depends elements such as folder permissions, how well a server is secured. In fact, renaming files does facilitate file management. e.g. trimming spaces, sorting, categorising, or invalid characters.